# HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /checkusername.jsp at line 11

Tags: java, jsp

**My code is**

```
<% 
 String sn=request.getParameter("ver");
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/publiccloud","root","root");
 Statement st=con.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from reg where Username='"+sn+"'");  // this is for name
```

Comment: your question is not clear!!

Comment: Independent of the current problem you should have a look at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A1-Injection

Comment: Please paste the complete code. There is only 5 line of code. Where is line no11 to debug your problem?